# Excel macro to save only values of a file with different file names

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to save my current excel file as a different file with file name as the value in the cell **B10** and taking only values (not formulas) from the current file.

I got the code for getting only values from this link: [Saving values from a workbook](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/702739-possible-save-excel-file-without-formulas-only-values.html)
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
I want to make a kind of template which will help my colleagues to document in a better way, without wasting disk space in formulas, which takes up about 1.7 mb per *.xls file. If I save only values, it takes about 600 kb. I want it to be flexible to different users, people who won't have to use long instructions to do this.
* vba isn't my area of expertise, and I haven't written any code for this work, so basically any possible way is welcome.

Comment: You tagged it [tag:vba] so I assume you need help with some code? If yes then [check this out and edit your question accordingly](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I hope this is not too much for you to attract more answers.

Comment: Yes, and I know vba is the best (only?) way to go, but vba is not my area of expertise at all. I want to make a kind of template which will help my colleagues to document in a better way, without wasting disk space in formulas, which take up about 1.7 mb per *.xls file. It has big formulas and borrowed data from other files. I have not written a single line of code in vba. I want it to be flexible to different users, people who won't have to use long instructions to do this.
I know my question literally asks for you to write the whole code for me, but I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the need

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
x = "C:\" 'path to file
y = Range("C1").Value 'Reference of the cell which contains the value
Z = x + y
Z = Z + ".xlsm" 'Format of macro enabled worksheet

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Z, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you provided a *Text only question*, I should give you a *Text Only Answer*.
To do what you want you have to:

1. Copy your worksheet using [*Sheets Object Copy method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb212205(v=office.12).aspx). It has optional arguments and if you omit it, it automatically creates a new workbook that contains the copied worksheet.
2. After copying, you can use *ActiveObject* (e.g. ActiveWorkbook, ActiveSheet etc.) to make reference to your newly created workbook and worksheet.
3. Once you have referenced the objects properly, you can now use [*Cells property*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567(v=office.15).aspx) to select all ranges and copy. Then use [*Range PasteSpecial Method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx) to convert formulas to values.
4. Lastly you'll need to save the workbook using the [*Workbook Object SaveAs Method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx).

Hope this somehow leads you to a solution. HTH.

Comment: Appreciate your comment and answer and I accept my mistake. Please read my edit, if it helps.

Comment: @fineashell Given that VBA is not your expertise (we all are before) still the best way to learn is to try something. Someone can give you a working code but if you don't understand how it works it's pointless. Now if you tried something and can't seem to make it work, then someone here will surely point you to the right direction. The best part of that is that we learn in the process.

Comment: I know, but I've been having a lot of things on my plate right now, learning a lot of other things, and I'm from a mechanical background that needs minimal programming. I do know C, SQL and R, however vba just keeps bugging me a lot because of its direct connection to Excel. I'll definitely find some time to learn it sometime soon. Thanks for bearing with this question though, I'll try not to repeat this!